# content not centered in viewbox and incorect mouse coord in viewbox

Tags: get, viewbox, uno-platform

Hi I am trying to port an app to android with uno platform. 
I am having a strange behavior of the viewbox in android, 
the following code work as expected in uwp version of the uno app I created for test.
- the viewbox content is not centered
-the mouse position is not exact

in MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid Background="#FF583793">
        <Viewbox  Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both">
            <Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas" Height="800" Width="800" Background="#FFA0ACA5" Margin="50,50,50,50" PointerPressed="UIElement_OnPointerPressed">
                <TextBlock x:Name="tblInfos" Height="64" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="780" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tblInfos2" Height="64" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="63" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="780" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Border x:Name="letter" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Height="200" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="300" Width="500" Background="#FF8D7E3B" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>

    </Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 private void UIElement_OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var posCanvas = e.GetCurrentPoint(mainCanvas).Position;
            var posLetter = e.GetCurrentPoint(letter).Position;
            tblInfos.Text = $"canvas x:{posCanvas.X} y:{posCanvas.Y}";
            tblInfos2.Text = $"letter x:{posLetter.X} y:{posLetter.Y}";

        }
```

May be i am missing something , or a possible bug ?

Answer (score 1):

ruler,

1. **Alignment:** I found that the default alignment of the ViewBox with Uno is top-left while it's center-center on UWP. I've created an issue for that: https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/2256 
   You can workaround the issue by specifying the `HorizontalAlignment` en `VerticalAligment`
2. **Pointers location:** It seems that the scaling is not taken in consideration when computing location relative to the target control. It's something that [I've already fixed on WASM](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/2091). I was under the feeling that it was OK on other platforms, but apparently not ... I've also created [an issue](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/2257) and I'm looking into it right now.

Answer (score 1):

this should now be resolved by [this PR](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/2392). It will be available soon on nuget in the "dev" preview package

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer. While it does hint to the OP's problem, the answers comprised from only links can lose their value very quickly

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, just set the value of Stretch property as None so that we could avoid the scaling of the ComboBox control.

If you want to use the scaling function of the Viewbox control, there is a workaround to fix the misalignment of the pointer in the scenario. You could try to set a very small rotation transform on the Viewbox control. The very small rotation won’t have any visible effect on screen.

For example:

```
<Viewbox Width="100" >  
    <Viewbox.RenderTransform>  
        <RotateTransform Angle="0.0001"/>  
    </Viewbox.RenderTransform>  
    <ComboBox x:Name="CbTest" >  
        <ComboBoxItem Content="a"/>  
        <ComboBoxItem Content="b"/>  
        <ComboBoxItem Content="c"/>  
        <ComboBoxItem Content="d"/>  
        <ComboBoxItem Content="e"/>  
        <ComboBoxItem Content="f"/>  
    </ComboBox>  
</Viewbox>
```